# Using groupBy to generate an excel with two sheet and two datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have two datasets df1 and df2

my goal is to create an excel-file with fruit name and inside file I want to create two sheets with customer details and second sheet with vender details.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"Fruit": ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "orange"],
"customerName": ["John", "Sam", "David", "Rebeca", "Sydney"],
"customerID": [877, 546, 767, 887, 890],
"PurchasePrice": [1, 2, 5, 6, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
"Fruit": ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "orange"],
"VenderName": ["share", "cami", "sniff", "tom", "Adam"],
"VenderID": [0091, 0092, 0094, 0097, 0076]})
```

I know how to do groupby with on dataset and generate a file.

```
grouped = df.groupby("Fruit")
# run this to generate separate Excel files
for fruit, group in grouped:
    group.to_excel(excel_writer=f"{fruit}.xlsx", sheet_name= customer, index=False)
```

Could please help to in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter


fruits = set(df1["Fruit"].unique().tolist() + df2["Fruit"].unique().tolist()) 
for fruit in fruits:
    sheets = {
        "Customer": df1.loc[df1["Fruit"].eq(fruit)],
        "Vendor": df2.loc[df2["Fruit"].eq(fruit)]
    }
    with ExcelWriter(f"{fruit}_.xlsx") as writer:
        for sh_name, table in sheets.items():
            table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sh_name, index=False)
```